# Javascript - Create parent-child navigation from json

Tags: javascript, html, json, recursion, navigation

I'm trying to create navigation from json using parent child relation. My json looks like this.

Somehow I'm getting maximum callstack exceeded error message while printing the navigation

```
 [
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 1,
    "Caption": "Master",
    "URL": "",
    "Description": "Main menu",
    "ParentID": ""
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 2,
    "Caption": "Branch Details",
    "URL": "~/UI/Masters/Branch_Details.aspx",
    "Description": "Branch Details",
    "ParentID": "1"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 123,
    "Caption": "Bank Details",
    "URL": "",
    "Description": "Bank Details",
    "ParentID": "1"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 124,
    "Caption": "Bank Details Entry",
    "URL": "~/UI/Loans/BankEntryRectification.aspx",
    "Description": "Bank Details Entry",
    "ParentID": "123"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 10,
    "Caption": "Loans&Printing",
    "URL": "",
    "Description": "",
    "ParentID": ""
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 11,
    "Caption": "Loan Form Request",
    "URL": "~/UI/Masters/LoanFormRequest.aspx?Type=General",
    "Description": "Loan Form Request",
    "ParentID": "10"
  }
]
```

I wrote a recursive function to loop through it, but somehow I'm getting maximum call stack exceeded error. The code I'm using is :

```
console.log(buildNavigation(data));

function buildNavigation(items, parent = '') {
  var next = function (items, parent) {
    return items.filter(function (item) {
      return (item.ParentID == parent);
    })
  }

  var output = '<ul>';

  for (var key in next(items, parent)) {
    output += '<li>';
    output += '<a href="#">' + items[key].Caption + '</a>';

    if (next(items, items[key].ID)) {
      output += buildNavigation(next(items, items[key].ID), parent);
    }

    output += '</li>';
  }

  output += '</ul>';

  return output;
}
```

Any Idea where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: It works fine for me. The output I'm getting is `<ul><li><a href="#">Master</a><ul></ul></li><li><a href="#">Branch Details</a><ul></ul></li></ul>`. If this is part of a larger file, are you modifying any variables or passing in the right data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, I wrote a working version. Please run the code snippet, and click the "Build Navigation" button to see if this is want you want.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 1,
    "Caption": "Master",
    "URL": "",
    "Description": "Main menu",
    "ParentID": ""
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 2,
    "Caption": "Branch Details",
    "URL": "~/UI/Masters/Branch_Details.aspx",
    "Description": "Branch Details",
    "ParentID": "1"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 123,
    "Caption": "Bank Details",
    "URL": "",
    "Description": "Bank Details",
    "ParentID": "1"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 124,
    "Caption": "Bank Details Entry",
    "URL": "~/UI/Loans/BankEntryRectification.aspx",
    "Description": "Bank Details Entry",
    "ParentID": "123"
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 10,
    "Caption": "Loans&Printing",
    "URL": "",
    "Description": "",
    "ParentID": ""
  },
  {
    "__type": "Service+Menu",
    "ID": 11,
    "Caption": "Loan Form Request",
    "URL": "~/UI/Masters/LoanFormRequest.aspx?Type=General",
    "Description": "Loan Form Request",
    "ParentID": "10"
  }
]

function buildNavigation(items, parent = '') {
  var next = function (items, parent) {
    return items.filter(function (item) {
      return (item.ParentID == parent);
    })
  }

  var output = '<ul>';
  
  var subItems = next(items, parent)
  for (var key in subItems) {
    output += '<li>';
    output += '<a href="#">' + subItems[key].Caption + '</a>';
    var subItems2 = next(items, subItems[key].ID)
    if (subItems2) {
      output += buildNavigation(items, subItems[key].ID);
    }

    output += '</li>';
  }

  output += '</ul>';

  return output;
}

document.querySelector('#build').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = buildNavigation(data)
}
```

```html
<button id="build">Build Navigation</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```